# Is it possible for me to create a Windows bootable USB flash drive using Linux running on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, bootable-media

I was going to install Linux Mint on my laptop, was of the idea that it would work for what I need my laptop for. Only it didn't as i'm not very smart when it comes to Linux in the first place.

I was trying to create a bootable USB on that laptop for Windows 10 again only I did something wrong and now Linux is of my laptop also, so there's no OS on it anymore.

The only thing I have left is a Raspberry Pi 4.

Now my question is, the Raspberry Pi has Kali Linux on it. Can i create a bootable USB flash drive for Windows with this Raspberry Pi or am I stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Use [WoeUSB-ng](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB-ng)

```
A Linux program to create a Windows USB stick installer from a real Windows DVD or image.

This package contains two programs:

woeusb: A command-line utility that enables you to create your own bootable Windows installation USB storage device from an existing Windows Installation disc or disk image
woeusbgui: Graphic version of woeusb
Supported images:

Windows Vista, Windows 7, Window 8.x, Windows 10. All languages and any version (home, pro...) and Windows PE are supported.

Supported bootmodes:

Legacy/MBR-style/IBM PC compatible bootmode
Native UEFI booting is supported for Windows 7 and later images (limited to the FAT filesystem as the target)
```

**Install WoeUSB-ng's Dependencies**

> Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install git p7zip-full python3-pip python3-wxgtk4.0
```

> Fedora (tested on: Fedora Workstation 33)

```
sudo dnf install git p7zip p7zip-plugins python3-pip python3-wxpython4
```

**Install WoeUSB-ng**

```
sudo pip3 install WoeUSB-ng
```

---

**Installation from source code**

Install WoeUSB-ng's Build Dependencies

> Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install git p7zip-full python3-pip python3-wxgtk4.0
```

> Arch

```
sudo pacman -Suy p7zip python-pip python-wxpython
```

> Fedora (tested on: Fedora Workstation 33)

```
sudo dnf install git p7zip p7zip-plugins python3-pip python3-wxpython4
```

**Install WoeUSB-ng**

```
git clone https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB-ng.git

cd WoeUSB-ng

sudo pip3 install .
```

**Installation from source code locally or in virtual environment**

```
git clone https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB-ng.git

cd WoeUSB-ng

git apply development.patch

sudo pip3 install -e .
```

*Please note that this will not create menu shortcut and you may need to run gui twice as it may want to adjust policy.*

**Uninstalling**

*To remove WoeUSB-ng completely run (needed only when using installation from source code):*

```
sudo pip3 uninstall WoeUSB-ng
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/WoeUSB-ng/icon.ico \
    /usr/share/applications/WoeUSB-ng.desktop \
    /usr/local/bin/woeusbgui
sudo rmdir /usr/share/icons/WoeUSB-ng/
```

---

Other methods

**Using ppa**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt update

sudo apt install woeusb
```

Comment: trying your guiding right now,the terminal is right now at the following message . ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy ... /
this was after i gave in the following code

Comment: sudo pip3 install WoeUSB-ng

Comment: ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-18k74sxm/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-3mo7ik_8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-18k74sxm/pillow/
root@kali:~# 
this is how far i am right now.

Comment: Seems that your PiP can't access Setuptools as per the "import setuptools" in the error. Try the below first then try running your pip install again  : sudo pip install -U setuptools && sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip ;

Comment: Successfully installed pip-21.1.3
and what do i donow?

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo apt install woeusb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package woeusb
root@kali:~#

Comment: I did these commands   git clone https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB-ng.git

cd WoeUSB-ng

git apply development.patch

sudo pip3 install -e .       No errors it seems

Comment: you have install it using pip : sudo pip3 install WoeUSB-ng ; not sudo apt install woeusb - it's not there in repos yet {alternatively you can add ppa to do so} ; anyways feel free to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: i'm so sorry for all this trouble. So i used your sudo pip3 command as posted above, this is what i get as a reply      Successfully built WoeUSB-ng
Failed to build wxPython
Installing collected packages: pillow, numpy, wxPython, WoeUSB-ng

is this good or bad?

Comment: wanted to keep you up to date,i just downloaded the win 10 iso, and if i right click on it it says open with WoeUSB.ng but nothing happens when i select it

Answer (score -1):

The typical way of creating a Windows installation media on DVD, ISO-file or USB-stick is by using Media Creation Tool which is available at Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

That will install the latest version available and will fit 90% of anybody's Windows installation needs.